# Issue while installing python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

I was reinstalling python to try to fix a problem i had, from there till now I can't find a solution to this problem.

The problem is that everytime I try to reinstall python, python scripts folder is always empty, meaning pip is not installed and I can't install anything.

I tried:

- Reinstalling on a different disc.
- Reinstalling with admin mode.
- Reinstalling a different version of python.
- Reinstalling the latest version of python.
- Reinstalling with different parameters.

I can't find the solution anywhere.

I'm using windows 10 latest version

**when I try to install pip using get-pip.py:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\get-pip.py", line 23704, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\get-pip.py", line 198, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\get-pip.py", line 83, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.commands.install import InstallCommand
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpazxzhdqd\pip.zip\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpazxzhdqd\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpazxzhdqd\pip.zip\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpazxzhdqd\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpazxzhdqd\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpazxzhdqd\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpazxzhdqd\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 982, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1040, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

**When i try to install pip using ensurepip:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "D:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 210, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "D:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "D:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfgi7l1sl\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfgi7l1sl\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfgi7l1sl\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfgi7l1sl\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfgi7l1sl\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfgi7l1sl\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfgi7l1sl\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfgi7l1sl\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\exceptions.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfgi7l1sl\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfgi7l1sl\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfgi7l1sl\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfgi7l1sl\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 982, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1040, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Python39\lib\ensurepip\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
  File "D:\Python39\lib\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 210, in _main
    return _bootstrap(
  File "D:\Python39\lib\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 129, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "D:\Python39\lib\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 38, in _run_pip
    return subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-c", code], check=True).returncode
  File "D:\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['D:\\Python39\\python.exe', '-c', '\nimport runpy\nimport sys\nsys.path = [\'C:\\\\Users\\\\Alex\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\tmpfgi7l1sl\\\\setuptools-57.4.0-py3-none-any.whl\', \'C:\\\\Users\\\\Alex\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\tmpfgi7l1sl\\\\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\'] + sys.path\nsys.argv[1:] = [\'install\', \'--no-cache-dir\', \'--no-index\', \'--find-links\', \'C:\\\\Users\\\\Alex\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\tmpfgi7l1sl\', \'--upgrade\', \'setuptools\', \'pip\']\nrunpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)\n']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: Are you in windows? Did you chose yo install pip in the installer?  And in any case you can always use [`get-pip.py` to install `pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)

Comment: I chose to install pip everytime I reinstalled. I am on windows

Comment: Just for confirmation, Can you check the by following command `python -m pip --version`

Comment: You got possible answer here in your previous question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69223708/pip-error-oserror-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor

Comment: Scan your system for malware which run in background and change files descriptors ... Also uninstall all antivirus programs

Comment: When i do `python -m pip --version` it says `D:\python39\python.exe: No module named pip`

Comment: I had this problem in the past but I just had to reinstall it in a different disc and it was solved

Comment: What was the original problem which caused you to reinstall Python?

Comment: Did you investigate the link to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6814 in the earlier comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69223708/pip-error-oserror-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor#comment122351195_69223708?

Comment: The original problem was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69223708/pip-error-oserror-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor and I wanted to try to reinstall to check if it fixes it but now im stuck with a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow installed python successfully.

### If someone else has this problem:

1. Uninstall python completely from your computer
2. Install python on C: (disc where windows is installed)
3. Restart your computer
4. Uninstall python from C:
5. Open python installation as administrator
6. Check `Add to path`
7. Click on `Customize installation`
8. Check everything except `install for all users` and `download debug binaries`
9. The install location should be any disc except C: (e.g: `D:, E:, F:`)
10. Click `install` and wait untill it installs

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to install python to C:, but that's how it fixed my issue.